# How should we deal with the name_scope's auto increment?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
def foo():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        with tf.name_scope("foo") as abso:
            print(abso)

for i in range(10):
    foo()
```

This is a simple code to test tf's `name_scope`.
The output of this code piece is

```
foo/
foo_1/
foo_2/
foo_3/
foo_4/
foo_5/
foo_6/
foo_7/
foo_8/
foo_9/
```

By which way, the piece code's output are all `foo/`s?

This is a question when I want to make my tf model a webapp.
The app can deal with the first request correctly.
But when it comes to the second or later request, it tries to load the graph as well as all variables with another `name_scope`(for example, `foo_1`) and it causes a fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the scope created by the `tf.name_scope` method and reuse it. For example:

```
scope = "foo"
def foo():
    global scope
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        with tf.name_scope(scope) as scope:
            print(scope)
for i in range(10):
    foo()
```

will print

```
foo/
foo/
foo/
foo/
foo/
foo/
foo/
foo/
foo/
foo/
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to add tf.reset_default_graph() before we establish the session and it works

Comment: It creates a new graph, so it probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6007. 
As mentioned in the above issue, you can use absolute name_scope like tf.name_scope("foo/") to prevent auto-increment.